# Now we're ready for tea

Tags: riddle

What is the riddle asking? What is the answer?

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!
But you won't need eyes to do so.
Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.
Now we're ready for tea, and with it, our answer!

HINT 1:

> The answer is heavily derived from a play on words.

HINT 2: (may be a spoiler, check only if you're completely stuck):

> Homonyms!

HINT 3:

> It has nothing to do with tea or biscuits.

HINT 4:

> You may not need eyes, but that does not mean you have to remove any.

HINT 5:

> The answer contains only one letter different than the question.

Comment: We have our answer with tea, so it must be biscuits!

Comment: @KSmarts ha, now a riddle with the question and answer as tea and biscuits would be a good one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution:

> When?  Then!

Explanation:

> Don't lose.  Do the opposite.  That's "win".  Something that sounds like "win" but has no 'I's (eyes) is "when".  That's the question.  Remove the 'W's (doubles) and add a 'T' (tea), and you get "then".  That's the answer.

Comment: Yes! I hope I didn't ruin it with too many hints.

Comment: case closed. I can go to bed.

Answer (score 13):

Don't lose

> *this one*

Remove the eye(s)

> = ths one.

Percolate *it* or "and with *it*" (not sure which one, maybe both)

> = ths one it

You *won't* need eyes (again)

> = ths one t

Remove doubles

> = hs one

Add *tea*('t') and rearrange

> = honest

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I was looking for, but great answer!

Comment: To elaborate, I'm looking for a question and answer that the riddle presents; "honest" doesn't fit that.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was thinking of! +1

Comment: @randal'thor There you are! But this answer is still incorrect. Where's your try?

Comment: Please stop fishing for votes and answers please...This site isn't about becoming "famous", really. So sad!

Comment: @Avigrail Who's "famous"? I now have over 3000 profile views :-o

Answer (score 5):

> the answer is hockey! it's the NHL

although it's very far fetched and if it's not it I won't bother posting how I got there.

My thinking:

> *Don't* plus *the opposite* makes it a double negative, so we start with "lose this one"

then

> we drop the "i" because "no eyes"

then

> we rearrange (percolate) the letters and drop the "doubles" 
>  LTHN -> NHLT

then

> we drop the "tea" 
>  NHL

Comment: You were close with how you approached it, but still not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!

> You should keep this one, but DO (process) the opposite. So keep *opposite*.

But you won't need eyes to do so.

> remove the *i* -> *opposte*

Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.

> Use *it* as a filter, removing the *t*. Then remove the doubles -> *se*

Now we're ready for tea,

> Add *t* -> *set*

and with it, our answer!

> *set it*, the  tea!

So
`What is the riddle asking?`

> The riddle is asking to [set the tea](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Table-for-a-Tea-Party)! Happy tea-time! :)

Comment: haha I love this answer, and I wish it were correct just from the creativity and thought that went into it.

Comment: Remember: question/answer

Answer (score 5):

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!

> So we "gain this one"

But you won't need eyes to do so.

> -which becomes "gan ths one"

Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.

> -then "hostage nn" -> "hostage"

Now we're ready for tea, and with it, our answer!

> So, "Who do we release at tea time? The hostage!"

Comment: You're the first to answer with both a question *and* answer as requested, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!

> Win that one

But you won't need eyes to do so.

> wnthatone

Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.

> Anagram and remove the t and n:
> whatnoe

Now we're ready for tea, and with it, our answer!

> Add "t" and "ti" is also our answer

Solution:

> What note? Ti!
> Clearly the best of the do-re-mi's.

Comment: You are the closest so far; you started out on the right path but then went awry. Keep trying!

Answer (score 2):

Another try, since my previous one wasn't quite right (leaving it up so others can potentially learn from it). I like my previous one better than this, but willing to give it another try.

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!

> Win that one

But you won't need eyes to do so.

> wnthatone

Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.

> anagram and drop n, t

You get:

> What one

Now we're ready for tea, and with it, our answer!

> Add the letters of "tea", and rearrange both to get the question and answer

You get:

> What one ate? Oaten wheat! Or Wheaten Oat :)

Comment: Nope! Same as my comment for your last answer. I may need to give another hint soon since a lot of answers are getting hung up on the same spot.

Comment: My other tactic is at the "remove any doubles" stage. I think that may be where I'm going wrong, and I think I know what I'm doing wrong, but haven't quite figured out the rest yet if I'm right about that.

Comment: Just added another hint.

Answer (score 2):

there is no "I" in TEAm, but there is an "I" in pie. And there's an "I" in meat pie. Anagram of meat is team...

yeah sorry about that it's just driving me crazy

Comment: Your first statement "there is no "I" in team" is on the right path for the start of the riddle. But no, this isn't a question/answer or correct. I believe in you, keep trying!

Comment: considering how much time I spent on this you owe my employer like 100 bucks xD

Comment: haha, well I hope you're the one to solve it then!

Comment: removing doubles (W) and adding tea (T) makes me think it has something to do with the words what and that

Comment: You are so close!

Comment: is the riddle literally asking "what is the answer"? so the the answer is "that" is the answer

Comment: no no, go back to your original comment that I said you were very close with. That is not the literal answer, think of it as a parallel. See how your thought process fits the riddle.

Answer (score 1):

The riddle is asking:

> What time is it.

The answer must be:

> Tea time

Don't lose this one, do the opposite!

> win that one

But you won't need eyes to do so.

> win that ne
>  Remove the "o" that looks like an eye

Then let it percolate, and remove any doubles.

> w i n t h a t n e
>  w h a t t i n e 
>  The second "W" is the only letter that is not reused.

Now we're ready for tea, and with it, our answer!

Just not sure how to connect the last dot there.....

Comment: See my hint about tea. But, you are very close with what the riddle is asking.

Comment: OH drat.... I totally spaced on that when I came back to it.

Comment: hey, you do have a double "n" in there. maybe they combine into a "m" somehow?

Comment: @user3453281 Hrm.. maybe. But it still isn't right either way :) Thanks for the encouragement though

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't lose this one

> `win this one`

2. But you won't need eyes to do so

> `wnthsone`

3. Then let it percolate and remove any doubles

> `wthsoe`

4. Now we're ready for tea, and with it our answer

> `twosthe` or `Tuesday`

Comment: No, not a question or answer.